# Understanding the array and loop answer

Tags: c

Can you go through all the steps as why is the answer is 9, 0 and 3.

This prints 9. How?

```
int sum,i, j, g[3][3] = {{0,0,0},{1,1,1},{2,2,2}};
sum = 0;
for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
        sum=sum+g[i][j];
}
printf("The value is:%d", sum);
```

This prints 0. How?

```
sum = 1;
for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=1;j++)
        sum=sum*g[i][j];
}
printf("The value is:%d", sum);`
```

This prints 3. How?

```
sum = 0;
for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
    sum=sum+g[i][1];
printf("The value is:%d", sum);
```

Comment: I think you should probably try to walk through the logic yourself first on this one; I could explain it, but the next assignment will require that you build this skill.  Your course of study will get unmanageable really fast if you don't learn how to walk your way through loops.

Comment: Idiomatic C would use `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` with a `<` rather than `<=` condition.  Also, in the second example, the term `sum` is a misnomer; it is a `product` that you're calculating (which is a hint about why you get the result 0).

Answer (score 0):

To see how it works try something like:

```
int sum,i, j, g[3][3] = {{0,0,0},{1,1,1},{2,2,2}};
sum = 0;
for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
     for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
     {
         sum=sum+g[i][j];
         printf("i=%d, j=%d, sum=%d", i, j, sum);
     }
}
printf("The value is:%d", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
int sum,i, j, g[3][3] = {{0,0,0},{1,1,1},{2,2,2}};
sum = 0;
for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
     for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
     {
         sum=sum+g[i][j];
         printf("i=%d, j=%d, g[%d][%d]=%d, sum=%d", i, j, i, j, g[i][j], sum);
     }
}
printf("The value is:%d", sum);
```